# How do I change/edit a drawn sprite?

Tags: java, swing, sprite, draw

I am working on a project that draws an ellipse centred at where the user clicks.

I need to make two buttons, <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>, which make the last ellipse drawn by the user rotate by 15 degrees.
I also need to make an **undo** button that removes the last ellipse the user drew.

Both of these tasks require reference to the last sprite drawn, so how would you refer to it? In other words, how would you change a drawn sprite?

Comment: This all depends on how you've implemented the functionality. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Momento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) is something you can use for this.

Comment: For the memento pattern, do I have to have 3 classes just for it, or can I put the originator, caretaker, and memento in the same class?

Comment: @Dariusisthebest. whatever works best for your situation.  I think anybody who answers this has to give a subjective response.